SOLR Searches - Issues with forward slash
I'm having issues with returning results from Solr that have a forward slash (/), if I search for something like - "Valid Publication Name 2019/20", it shows 0 results, while running "Valid Publication Name 2019" it brings back the result.
The code is similar to the following:
            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultModel>();

           //// Search the whole phrase with fuzzy logic to include special characters - LIKE
            predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Title.Like(searchText)).Boost(6.0f); //title get the highest priority
            predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Name.Like(searchText)).Boost(5.5f);
            predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Content.Like(searchText)).Boost(4.0f);
            predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Renderpagecontent.Like(searchText)).Boost(3.0f);
            
            BooleanQuery.MaxClauseCount = int.MaxValue;
            var allResults = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultModel>).Where(predicate).Take(maxNumResults).ToList()

As per Solr documentation a forward slash doesn't need escaping, so not sure why this is happening?
Please could someone help!!
Thanks in advance.

Can you make below changes on search predicate while creating Solr query.
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<SearchResultModel>();
predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Title.Contains(searchText));

BooleanQuery.MaxClauseCount = int.MaxValue;
var allResults = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultModel>).Where(predicate).Take(maxNumResults).ToList()


This will sent query to Solr in below format.
?q==title_t:(*Valid* *Publication* *Name* *2019* *20*)

Let me know in case you face any issues. Hope this helps!!!

Thanks CKhanna, but this did not seem to work, actually I also tried to remove all the other fields from predicate, with the changes you suggested, so predicate is as below:
predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Title.Like(searchText)).Boost(10000.0f); //title get the highest priority

I've done the reindexing also, but it doesn't even return anything with a query like "Valid Publication Name". Not sure what I'm missing, do I need to do any other config changes for title field please?

I've also tried using the Solr API directly, the URL is similar to following:
https://localhost:8983/solr/sitecore_web_content/select?q=title_s:"Valid Publication Name 2020/21"
https://localhost:8983/solr/sitecore_web_content/select?q=title_s:"Valid Publication Name"
Both return results similar to following:
{
"responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":0,
"params":{
"q":"title_s:"Valid Pulication NAme 2020/21""}},
"response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
}}

@MaverickHT Did you checked the field is getting indexed with suffix '_s' in the Solr and can you also check the Solr query in the Search logs.

Schema in solr the index doesn't have this fld, are any other config changes to get this done, following is config: 





Thanks for your help!

@MaverickHT Since the title field is changed to string type now, you will need to rebuild index from Control Panel.Therefafter you should be able to see this field with name 'title_s' inside Solr index.Let me know in case you still face any issue.

Thanks @CKhanna, I've tried rebuilding the index, but the title_s field is not there I tried deleting all the index data also in Solr directory and Populate Solr Managed Schema and then rebuild index, but nothing seems to work. Its just not adding title_s to the index, I cannot see that in the Schema of the index either, and the query similar to https://localhost:8983/solr/sitecore_web_content_tis/select?title_s=code gives:
{
"responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":0,
"params":{
"title_s":"code"}},
"response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
}}

@MaverickHT Did you checked the showconfig..Your changes for setting title fieldname as string type is reflecting? We can connect on slack in case required.

\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config has:



But in ShowConfig its showing as:




I have an include file for the custom index, where I'd added new field map also, but commented it because it was already in Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config
the ShowConfig irrespective of that still shows returntype="text"
And the index doesn't have a field called title, even after the Populate Solr Managed Schema and then rebuild index
I'm stumped, really appreciate your help, I hardly use slack, but I can if we can connect, how should I find you there.

@MaverickHT you can search me on the sitecore slack with name Chirag Khanna. we can connect there.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
